# Lifetime of an object

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm expecting a strange issue with object lifetime. I instantiated a struct in a scope (Beginning of the scope). This object is as follows :

```
struct Spy
{
    Spy(const std::string& p_name) : name(p_name) 
    { 
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    ~Spy() 
    { 
        Destroy();
    }

    void Destroy()
    {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        Save();
    }

    std::string name;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

    void Save() { Profiler::Save(*this); }
};
```

The goal is to calculate the Spy lifetime, so the timer should start at the creation (Ctor) and the timer should stop and save data in another class on destroy (Dtor).

Here is the spy usage :

```
ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy spy("PostUpdate");
if (m_enableRendering)
{
    m_windowManager->GetDriver()->ClearScreen();
    RenderScene();
    m_windowManager->GetDevice()->SwapBuffers();
}

m_inputManager->Update();
Context::Device::PollEvents();
spy.Destroy();
```

This code works well, but when I don't call the destroy method (That should get called by the dtor) the elapsed time (end - start) is very very low (0.0000001). Is it due to the compiler optimization ? Does the compiler detect that I don't invoke any method of this object so it destroy it from the stack ?

EDIT :
Well, I got my answer. The problem was that I was using a macro to create the spy as follows :

```
#define PROFILER_SPY(name) \
  if (ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::__RUNNING) \
    ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy __profiler_spy__(name)
```

But I totally forget that my if statement is a scope, so outside of the if the spy is destroyed..... Do you have any idea to keep checking the condition without destroying the spy at the if statement ?

Comment: No, your compiler definitely does not do that. C++ does not work this way. Whatever your problem is, it's not that.

Comment: Can you show the full scope (all the code) in which Spy is constructed and destructed?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a Spy object only if `ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::__RUNNING` is true?

Comment: @eozd yes exactly, but it seems being impossible to create it in a if scope because it will get destroyed. So the idea I just have is to create a boolean "enable" to avoid calculating time and sending it if the profiler isn't running

Comment: Why not make the condition part of the Spy implementation, rather than at the callsite? Or even better, part of the Profiler::Save implenentation. Given that calling now() is pretty cheap, it (probably) wouldn't be the end of the world if your spy took timepoints and called Save only yo have the Profiler conditionally ignore them on __RUNNING

Comment: Also careful with having destroy as part of Spy's public interface. If Destroy is called and then the Spy is destructed, I imagine your profiling logs might get confusing.

Comment: @definecindyconst Thanks for your comment, I tried to use __RUNNING in the implementation of the spy, but the problem is that when I call a method something like thousands of times I can see my framerate going down even if they dont send any data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr` would be a reasonable fix for something like this.

```
#define PROFILER_SPY(name) \
    std::optional<ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy> __profiler_spy__ = \
        ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::__RUNNING
        ? std::make_optional<ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy>(name)
        : std::nullopt
```

Or with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#define PROFILER_SPY(name) \
    std::unique_ptr<ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy> __profiler_spy__ = \
        ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::__RUNNING
        ? std::make_unique<ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::Spy>(name)
        : nullptr
```

Comment: If you want to avoid heap memory allocations you could move the check to inside `Spy` and only call `Profiler::Save` if the profiler is running.

Comment: Thank you ! You saved me a lot of frames :) I tried to call the macro thousands of spies per frame and with std::unique_ptr performances are much better

Answer (score 1):

just use a std::unique_ptr as a guard and construct it in a factory.

```
std::unique_ptr<Spy> SpyFactory()
{
if (ElkTools::Utils::Profiler::__RUNNING)
     return std::make_unique<Spy>()
else
     return nullptr;
}
```

to disable profiling, just let the factory return a nullptr, let the compiler optimize the rest :)

be sure not to call .Destroy() on nullptr :)